# Time Complexity of nested if, compared to multiple cases in while

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am looking at the time complexity of various solutions, and since I am not much of a math lover; I can't quite figure out the best time complexity for my call.

The problem is that I am not sure if it takes longer to get trough a while loop with 1 statement, and nested if-else, or if it is better to remove the nested if-else and add the check in the while loop.

As generic example would this perform faster

```
while a>1 and b is True
    if x is True:
        a -= 1
    else
        a += 1
```

instead than

```
while a>1:
    if x is True:
        if  b is True:
            a -= 1
        else:
            a += 1
```

I recall that nested if result in O(N^2), while a simple while loop has complexity O(n), but what happens when the while loop has to check multiple statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I recall that nested if result in O(N^2)

Wrong, a nested `for` loop has a complexity of `O(N^2)` not an `if`.

If you have an array of size N and you do

```
for i in arr:
    for j in arr:
        print "hello"
```

How many times will you see "hello" printed? N^2, which is the complexity.

Note that it doesn't matter what you doing inside your loops (whether you are printing, adding, doing an if statement), that is all a fixed cost. And so the fact that you are re-arranging your if statements doesnt matter - both cases have the exact same complexity.

What matters is how often that "body" of code inside your while loop is executed, and that's what determines the complexity.

So let's because both of your examples have the same complexity, let's break down the first one:

```
while a>1 and b is True
    if x is True:
        a -= 1
    else
        a += 1
```

`b` appears to be an independent variable, so we should be able to ignore that. if `x` is `True`, your time complexity is infinity, since the while loop will never end (at least until the integer `a` overflows to negative. Note this means your statement "while loop has complexity O(n)" is also wrong). If `x` is `False`, your code has a time complexity of `O(a-1)` (or simply `O(a)`), since it will run through `a-1` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

**Both have complexity of O(n)**, n related to while loop iteration. If else statements doesn't change this. Just think about it: How your iteration count scale, when your input variable goes to infinity? Linearly? Cubicly? Or else?

For example check this pseudo-code:

```
for(x time)
    for(y time)
        for(z time)
            do ....
            if(z=x+y)
```

We have nested loops, 3 times. So complexity is O(x * y * z) which is simply O(n^3). You don't care if condition, because doesn't scale iteration count when variables go to infinity.

When deciding complexity, you should generally check for nested loops and check which variables are significant for iteration count.

I also recommend to read this: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html

It's a deep topic after all.

Comment: Big-O notation represents algebraic relation with run time and input variables, **when input variables goes to infinity**. Because of this, asymptotically, slower growing variables goes to 0. So, it gets insignificant whether you go if way or else way. You should really read about these, they are not that simple to explain it all here.

Comment: I think you are a computer science student which is taking algorithm analysis course right now, am I wrong? :)